# Crud con netbeans alta de un registro de una tabla dependiente de otra

Tags: java, netbeans

```
protected void processRequest(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String id = request.getParameter("txtId");
        String nombre = request.getParameter("txtNombre");
        String direccion = request.getParameter("txtDireccion");
        String telefono = request.getParameter("txtTelefono");
        String idproveedor = request.getParameter("txtProveedor");

        if(id.equals("")||nombre.equals("")||direccion.equals("")||telefono.equals("")||idproveedor.equals("")){
          String error = "Complete los Campos";
          request.getSession().setAttribute("error", error);
          request.getRequestDispatcher("error.jsp").forward(request, response);           
        }
        else{
            Personal personal = new Personal();

            personal.setPersonalPK(personalPK);
            personal.setNompersonal(nombre);
            personal.setDirpersonal(direccion);
            personal.setTelpersonal(telefono);
            personal.setProveedor(proveedor);
        }
}
```

Este es mi código, recibo de una pagina jsp los valores de un formulario, que son el id, nombre, direccion, telefono y proveedor(es la llave foranea).
me marca el código un error en la llave primaria puesto que todos tipos de datos los estoy manejando como string y en el id espera un objeto personalPK y yo le quiero agregar el id que es String. NO ME LO PERMITE.

Answer (score 0):

crea un objeto PersonalPK y con los metodos modificadores (setters) setear el id tienes que verificar que el id sea un entero si no lo transformas con el metodo Integer.parseInt(cadena) luego a tu clase personal le seteas el personalPk

```
PersonaPK pk = new PersonaPK(Integer.parseInt(id));
personal.setPersonalPK(pk);
```